# shell script to perform git pull. Problems with password

Tags: git, shell, ssh, bamboo, ssh-agent

I wrote a shell script to do project releasing with Git which would be integrated n bamboo, in the shell script I first cd to the Git working copy and then do git pull origin master.
But it prompts me for password: git@localhost's password:Any idea on how to solve this? I already tried using ssh-agent but for some reason ssh-add command does nothing.

Comment: Can you use a ssh key file instead of a password? This works for me.

Comment: you dont want it ask for password?

Comment: Could you please give more details about the ***exact commands*** you tried to use for `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`?

Comment: I do want it to ask for password but since I am using bamboo I can not  have the user enter password for every single run.I probable could use ssh key file but I'm not sure how to do that. Any good links to proceed in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ssh keys with ssh-agent.  I successfully setup my ssh key and ssh-agent configurations using information on [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git).

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your ssh keys.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys